# Renaming files with a pattern

Tags: python, file-io, file-rename

Python beginner here.

I have a directory with hundreds of image files named as (in sequence):

**002_IMG_001, 002_IMG_002, 002_IMG_003, 002_IMG_N**

Now, I am trying to rename those images such that the five files in a row have 'N' from 1:5, that is, every consecutive set of five images get N, 1 to 5. I would also like to stick another string before the number 'N'. This string will keep track of the set of N images, e.g, IMG_001_1, IMG_001_2,.. IMG_001_N, IMG_002_1,IMG_002_2,...**IMG_00X_N**.

The pseudo code on python 2.7.10 on Mac looks like this:

```
import os

myDir = "/Users/path/to/dir/"
fileList = os.listdir(myDir)

for filename in fileList :
    #split the images into sets of five each
    newFile = 'IMG_' + '00' + X + '_' + N
        #loop through images and rename
            os.rename(fileName, newFile)
```

I think I need a condition inside for loop, somthing like:

```
 if int(filename[9:12]) % 5 == 0
```

but this would mean, I have to create five separate conditions for 1 to 5, which doesn't seem right. Any hint would be appreciated ?

Edit: It wasn't clear to some what kind of output was required. I am looking for a function to get the final file names like: IMG_001_1, IMG_001_2,...IMG_001_5, IMG_002_1, IMG_002_2,...IMG_002_5,...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your renaming rules. Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: So they go 001...,002...,003...?

Comment: Confirm you want to transform this filename 002_IMG_001 into what exactly - place  this answer into your question not in a comment

Comment: are you also stating that every file name begins with 002.  Thus, you could have 002_IMG_2345

Comment: This is not really a file renaming problem, this is an issue relating to how to pick 5 items from a list of items at a time. I was tempted to answer it but I think there are plenty of explanations on how to pick n items from a list at one time here on StackOverflow.

Comment: `for file in dir:` does not provide them in alphabetical order... if you want to preserve the order of the files you have to sort the list.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking— Do you want a function to generate the filenames in that pattern? Are the current names relevant at all? Do you need help actually writing the names to files?

Comment: Joe has answered the question partially. All that is left is to have some way to access the original file name inside the for loop to rename the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
my_list = ["002_IMG_001", "002_IMG_002", "002_IMG_003", "002_IMG_004", "002_IMG_005",
       "002_IMG_006", "002_IMG_007", "002_IMG_008", "002_IMG_009", "002_IMG_0010",
       "002_IMG_011", "002_IMG_012", "002_IMG_013", "002_IMG_014", "002_IMG_015",
       "002_IMG_016", "002_IMG_017", "002_IMG_018", "002_IMG_019", "002_IMG_0020",
       ]
fileList.sort()

print("Original list:\n")
print(fileList)

new_list = []

for index, old_file_name in enumerate(fileList):
    group, subgroup = divmod(index,5)
    group, subgroup = group + 1, subgroup + 1
    new_file_name = "IMG_{0:03d}_{1}".format(group, subgroup)
    new_list.append(new_file_name)

    os.rename(old_file_name, new_file_name)

print("\nNew list:\n")
print (new_list)
```

Here is the output:

```
Original list:

['002_IMG_001', '002_IMG_002', '002_IMG_003', '002_IMG_004', '002_IMG_005', 
'002_IMG_006', '002_IMG_007', '002_IMG_008', '002_IMG_009', '002_IMG_0010', 
'002_IMG_011', '002_IMG_012', '002_IMG_013', '002_IMG_014', '002_IMG_015', 
'002_IMG_016', '002_IMG_017', '002_IMG_018', '002_IMG_019', '002_IMG_0020']

New list:

['IMG_001_1', 'IMG_001_2', 'IMG_001_3', 'IMG_001_4', 'IMG_001_5', 
'IMG_002_1', 'IMG_002_2', 'IMG_002_3', 'IMG_002_4', 'IMG_002_5', 
'IMG_003_1', 'IMG_003_2', 'IMG_003_3', 'IMG_003_4', 'IMG_003_5', 
'IMG_004_1', 'IMG_004_2', 'IMG_004_3', 'IMG_004_4', 'IMG_004_5']
```

Comment: Exatcly the output I needed. Just one comment: we also need to access the original filename inside the for loop to rename the files at the end -- perhaps a nested for loop ? Do you have any suggestion on that ?

Comment: I just edited the code. No need to nest another loop. See the 'enumerate' keyword in the 'for' loop. This makes both the index and the list item available in the 'for' loop. I have another suggestion. The listdir may not necessarily list the directory items in alphabetical order. You may want to add a statement  "fileList.sort()" statement before the loop. Don't assign anything to that statement. It sorts the original list permanently.

Comment: Added "fileList.sort()" and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot !